# Allocate Array of bitset<N> on heap

Tags: c++, arrays, stack-overflow, bitset

I'm creating an array of bitsets on the stack using this code:

```
int Rows = 800000;
int Columns = 2048;

bitset<Columns> data[Rows];
```

If I don't raise the stack size to hundreds of Megabytes, I get an stack overflow error.

Is there any way to allocate this code on the heap? for example with a code like this (I'm not even sure if this code is right):

```
bitset<Columns>* data[Rows] = new bitset<Columns>();
```

**Edit:** And more importantly, does this help memory usage or speed? Does it make any difference whether I use the Stack or the Heap for this? I really don't want to use any other libraries such as Boost too...

I come from a Java background and some C++ syntax is new for me, Sorry if the question seems kind of wrong.

Comment: `bitset<Columns>* data = new bitset<Columns>[Rows];`

Comment: You may use [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) instead. (It's specialized.)

Comment: First of all `new bitset<Columns>()` allocates and default-constructs *one* `bitset` object. You probably want something like `bitset<Columns>* data = new bitset<Columns>[Rows];`. [Any good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would have told you that. With that said, you should really be using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: "do I have to allocate hundreds of Megabytes to the Heap also?" - well, `800,000 x 2,048 / 8` *is* `204,800,000` bytes no matter which was you look at it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but I read elsewhere (in Stackoverflow) that the bitset's performance is superior to the std::vector. I come from a Java background would you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: @Rotem Actually I meant manually changing the default Heap size opposed to C++ automatically extending it. By the way is this possible or should I always change the Heap size by hand just like the Stack size?

Comment: @Cypher You don't mention the platform or compiler you're working with but normally the heap will allocate more memory as required.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks... I'm using Visual C++ 2015 by the way.

Comment: I mean a vector *of* bitsets. Like `std::vector<std::bitset<Columns>> data(rows);`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<bitset>
#include<vector>

constexpr int Rows = 800000;
constexpr int Columns = 2048;

int your_function() {
  std::vector<std::bitset<Columns> > data (Rows);

  // do something with data
}
```

This will allocate the memory on the heap and it will still take whatever amount of memory it took before (plus a few bytes for bookkeeping). The heap however is not limited by a fixed size like the stack, but mainly limited by how much memory the system has, so on a reasonably modern PC you should be fine with a few hundred megabytes.

I am not sure if that was your concern, but bitset's memory usage is not inefficient- `sizeof(std::bitset<2048>) == 256` on gcc so you do not waste a single bit there.

Answer (score 1):

Storing this in the inverse way:

```
int Rows = 2048;
int Columns = 800000;

bitset<Columns> data[Rows];
```

Will save you almost 18Mb, and it is better for data locality.

In the first method If you calculate how much memory you are using:

```
A = (24 * 800000) + 800000 * (2048/8) = 224x10^6 bytes
```

In the other hand, it you swap the row size with the column size the memory you will be using is:

```
B = (24 * 2048) + 2048 * (800000/8) = 204,849x10^6 bytes
```

where 24 is the fixed size in bytes of a vector object in C++ in most systems.
So in the second case you are reducing the memory usage by using less vectors.

```
A - B = 19150448 bytes = 18,26 Mb
```

This is not the answer but it can inderctly help you solve your problem.

Comment: That's still a tremendous amount of data to put "on the stack".

Comment: Yes indeed, but it makes sense to bring it out, since thinking about our data structures is fundamental when performance, timewise and memory wise is a real concern.

Comment: Well, exactly  That's why you _wouldn't_ do this ;)